# Conway's Game of Life F#

Tags: f#, game-of-life

I am a C# developer learning F#. Would appreciate any suggestions on how this code can be improved. Main points I am interested in:

- Functional style of the code, absense of imperative style(C#) artifacts
- F# collection data types and functions usage
- General code(not algorithm) efficiency
- Code style, naming etc.

  ```
  let life board =
      let flatten = Seq.cast<int> >> Seq.toArray

      let neighboursCount (board: int[,]) x y =
          board.[y..y+2, x..x+2]
          |> flatten
          |> Array.mapi (fun i el -> (i <> 4, el))
          |> Array.filter fst |> Array.map snd
          |> Array.filter ((=) 1) |> Array.length

      let expandBoard board =
          let N = Array2D.length1 board
          array2D [|
              yield                        [| yield board.[N - 1, N - 1]; yield! board.[N - 1, *]; yield board.[N - 1, 0] |]
              for i in [0..N - 1] do yield [| yield board.[i,     N - 1]; yield! board.[i,     *]; yield board.[i,     0] |]
              yield                        [| yield board.[0,     N - 1]; yield! board.[0,     *]; yield board.[N - 1, 0] |]
          |]

      let getNextBoard board =
          let eBoard = expandBoard board
          board |> Array2D.mapi (fun i j elem ->
              match neighboursCount eBoard j i with
              | 2 -> elem
              | 3 -> 1
              | _ -> 0)

      let isGameOver board prevBoards =
          board |> flatten |> Array.forall ((=) 0) || List.contains board prevBoards

      let rec lifeRec board prevBoards =
          printfn "%A \n" board
          if isGameOver board prevBoards
          then ()
          else getNextBoard board |> lifeRec <| board::prevBoards

      lifeRec board []

  let N = 5
  let rnd = System.Random()
  Array2D.init N N (fun _ _ -> rnd.Next 2) |> life
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This is a most elegant solution. I have two small improvements:

---

```
let neighboursCount (board: int[,]) x y =
    board.[y..y+2, x..x+2] 
    |> flatten 
    |> Array.indexed
    |> Array.sumBy (fun (i, n) -> if i <> 4 then n else 0)
```

---

```
let expandBoard board =
    let N = (Array2D.length1 board) - 1
    array2D [|
        yield                    [| yield board.[N, N]; yield! board.[N, *]; yield board.[N, 0] |]
        for i in [0..N] do yield [| yield board.[i, N]; yield! board.[i, *]; yield board.[i, 0] |]
        yield                    [| yield board.[0, N]; yield! board.[0, *]; yield board.[N, 0] |]
    |]
```

Here is `N` set to `(Array2D.length1 board) - 1` because that's the value you're using through out the function.

Answer (score 0):

Review for the updated version (because there are no answers yet, I think you can still remove the first version).

I really like your implementation. Especially the idea of expanding the board instead of calculating the opposide indices [as i did](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154587/compact-game-of-life-implementation)). That makes the code much more readable / understandable. I also like the way you imlemented the `neighboursCount` function - the  combination of `mapi`, `filter` and `map` is a good example for functional programming.

In fact, I don't see much room for improvement.

Maybe you could rename `neighboursCount` into `countNeighbours` an move the `board` to the end of the argument list so it can be used like: `eBorad |> countNeighbours j i`

Within the `isGameOver` function, I think I would prefer writing `prevBoards |> List.contains board` over `List.contains board prevBoards`.

Thanks for sharing your solution :).

Comment: I believe `neighboursCount` came from my OO background, where you name object properties like that.
Also that is a bit unusual that I can use piping where it seems to be unneded, but in fact version with piping is much more readable, so I accept your point.